# How to limit number of nodes a user can create per day?

Tags: nodes, rules, advertising

In order to curb ardent spammers in Drupal 6, I'd like to limit the number of forum nodes that an authenticated user can create per day. So for example ordinary users can not create more than 3 posts each day. I am wondering how can I do so? Thanks

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/node_limit

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 6 I have used [Node Limit Number](http://drupal.org/project/node_limitnumber) with great success.

> Limit the amount of nodes or comments your users create over a given
>   time period. This module has been rewritten to integrate with Rules.
>   Instead of going to a page to assign limits you now just need to
>   create rules. A default rule has been provided as an example.

The 2.x branch also integrates with the Rules module to make it really flexible.

Comment: I could figure out how to define how to define rules for this module. I appreciate further elaboration.